# Set sound output device using vlcj

Tags: java, vlcj

I would like to set my vlcj created player to output sound to virtual audio cable, is it possible? The vlcj player doesn't seem to inherit the options from the native player, so I dont really know how I could change the output. Thanks

edit: This is basically how far i've gotten, but nothing actually happens:

```
mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().setPlaySubItems(true);

    List<AudioOutput> outputs = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayerFactory().getAudioOutputs();

    for (AudioOutput i : outputs) {
        System.out.println(i);
        List<AudioDevice> devices = i.getDevices();
        if (!devices.isEmpty()) {
            for (AudioDevice itdev : devices) {
                System.out.println(itdev.getDeviceId());
            }
        }
    }
    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().setAudioOutputDevice(outputs.get(5).getDevices().get(3).toString(), outputs.get(5).getDevices().get(3).toString());
```

Comment: the console output would maybe be useful

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your "virtual audio cable" is a specific audio output device.

So, get the list of `AudioOutput` from the `MediaPlayerFactory`.

Enumerate that list of outputs to find the one you want, by name.

When you find the audio output you want, you can inspect the list of `AudioDevice` associated with that output.

When you find the audio device you want, set it on the `MediaPlayer`. There are `setAudioOutput()` and `setAudioOutputDevice()` methods there.

The associated vlcj-player project at github shows one way to build a menu of audio devices and allows you to select one.

Comment: Hm, thank you but im not really getting anywhere with it:( Please see edited opener post